# Clicking check boxes based on text with Eggplant

Tags: automation, automated-tests, eggplant

I am trying to create a generic handler for selecting a checkbox. But by Generic I mean it’s able to pick it based on the next next to the check box. Like a row of check boxes that say “Option 1, option 2 , Option 3” with the checkbox a little to the left of the text and the three options placed in a column.

The below code errors imagefound Error - Invalid Rectangle: MySearchRect (its saying it either cant find the rectangle or the coordinates are not right or not valid
​
To handle SelectBox

params Check_Name

Set SearchRectangle to my QueryPaneSRC

set the TextLocation to ImageRectangle (text:(Check_Name))

set Check_Name to (left to TextLocation – 35, right of TextLocation, top of TextLocation – 3, right of the RemoteScreenRectangle, the bottom of TextLocation + 2)

put MySearchRect

If ImageFound(ImageName:”Images/Box_UNCHECKED”, searchRectangle: MySearchRect

Then

```
 Click FoundImageLocation()
```

Return
Else

ImageFound(ImageName:”Images/Box_CHECKED”, searchRectangle: MySearchRect

Return
End if

End SelectBox

Run SelectBox ”Option 1”

Comment: "set Check_Name to (left to TextLocation " : is it left "to" or left "of" ?

Comment: you should put "Check_Name" instead because the coordinates are stored in "Check_Name" 
And your "Check_Name" coordinates parameters should have only 4 parameters. In the Code above, you've given 5 parameters....